# TweenMax: multiple elements with sequential variables

Tags: gsap

is there a way to do something like `+1` for delays when tweening an array / object collection?

Let's say `models` includes 5 elements and I want to show them sequentially with a difference of `.2` seconds after at least 1 second delay.

Normally I'd do an `for` / `$.each` loop, tween every element itself and calculate the `delay` like this: `delay: 1 + (index * .2)`

Is there a way to do this without my own wrapping loop? Like `delay: + .2` or something?

```
var models = $('.model img');
TweenMax.from(models, 1, {
    opacity: 0,
    transform: 'translateZ(-80px)',
    delay: 1,                 // how to delay each element differently?
    clearProps: 'all',
    onComplete: function() {
        console.log('animation complete');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.staggerFrom` is what I was searching for! It is pretty much a separate Tween for every element in the array/collection.
The fifth parameter is `stagger` and specifies the time between the tweens for each element.

> Amount of time in seconds (or frames for frames-based tweens) to
>   stagger the start time of each tween. For example, you might want to
>   have 5 objects move down 100 pixels while fading out, and stagger the
>   start times by 0.2 seconds - you could do: TweenMax.staggerTo([mc1,
>   mc2, mc3, mc4, mc5], 1, {y:"+=100", opacity:0}, 0.2).

Source: http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/staggerTo/

The wrapped loop that I'd tried has the disadvantage that the `onComplete` function is called for every iteration. The same is true for `staggerFrom`/`staggerTo` but this function has `onCompleteAll` as described in the source link. But it's the 6th parameter, not a property of the data/options obect. It will fire after all animations for all elements are complete.

Example:

```
TweenMax.staggerFrom(
    '.model img', 
    1, // <-- this is the overall delay
    {
        opacity: 0,
        transform: 'translateZ(-50px)',
        delay: .3,
        onComplete: function() {
            // a single animation is complete
        }
    }, 
    .2, // <--- this is the time between the tweens.
    function() {

        // all animations are complete

    }
);
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @MortenJensen This answer is by the original poster, so I'm assuming it really is the answer to the question.  However the answer could be more complete.  Explaining how `.staggerForm` solves the problem could be useful for those who find the post via Google.